# Postgresql: Sorting Null+ true and false for list of items

Tags: postgresql, sorting

I need to sort the following table:

```
id  accepted  priority

156    NULL        3
157    t           6
158    t           2
159    f           5
160    f           3
```

in a such a way that first the sorting is on the basis of "accepted" column and then on the basis of priority.
I'm able to do it upto some extent by:

```
ORDER BY accepted DESC , priority DESC
```

But I want the list to be displayed in such a way that rows having accepted as NULL is accompanied with the rows having accepted as true, then sub-sorting would be on the basis of priority.

Hence the final table that I would be needing is:

```
id  accepted  priority

157    t           6
156    NULL        3    
158    t           2
159    f           5
160    f           3
```

Comment: try `order by case when accepted or accepted is null then 1 else 0 end DESC, , priority DESC`

Comment: `ORDER BY COALESCE(accepted, true) DESC , priority DESC` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use coalesce to make it replace NULL with true in the order by.  This won't affect the data returned in the select.

```
select * from table
order by coalesce(accepted,true) desc, priority desc
```